# Why would gulp.watch not run on a windows computer when the same code executes on other windows computers?

Tags: javascript, node.js, powershell, gulp, gulp-watch

I'm helping a remote coworker to setup with gulp on their Windows 10 computer, and have ran into an issue where the watch function in gulp simply will not work.

Other gulp functionality works well, but watch in particular just hangs without any error to the screen.

To ensure I'm not missing anything in my code, I made a simple test gulpfile to be sure that this wasn't due to some other reason.

---

**gulpfile.js**

```
var gulp = require("gulp");
var fs = require('fs');
var compareToPreviousRead = require("./fileReaderTest.js");

gulp.task("watch", function(){
    return gulp.watch("Test.txt", async function(){
        var diff = await compareToPreviousRead();
        console.log(`Diff: "${diff}", Time: "${new Date().toGMTString()}"`);
        Promise.resolve(true);
    });
});
```

---

**fileReaderTest.js**

```
var fs = require('fs');

var readTestFile = () => new Promise(resolve => {
    fs.readFile('Test.txt', 'utf8', (err, contents) => resolve(contents));
});

var originalValue = "";

var compareToPreviousRead = () => new Promise(resolve => {
    readTestFile().then(updatedValue => {
        var diff = updatedValue.replace(originalValue, "");
        originalValue = updatedValue;
        resolve(diff);
    });
});

module.exports = compareToPreviousRead
```

---

I also included a few PowerShell Scripts to install and run the app from the same directory. 
Someone could also just manually edit a file called "Test.txt" in the same directory (only appending to the file) and the gulp task would work correctly.

---

**WriteToFileEverySecond.ps1**

```
param ($testFileLocation)

Start-Sleep -Seconds 1
$i = 0
for ($i=0; $i -lt 10; $i++){
    [System.IO.File]::AppendAllText($testFileLocation, "$i--", [System.Text.Encoding]::Ascii)
    Start-Sleep -Seconds 1
}
```

---

**TestGulpWatch.ps1**

```
$currDir = $PSScriptRoot

cd $currDir

npm install --silent

Remove-Item "$currDir/Test.txt" -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue > $null
New-Item "Test.txt" -ItemType File > $null

$job1 = Start-Job -ScriptBlock {
    param($currDir)
    cd $currDir
    gulp watch --silent
} -ArgumentList $currDir

Start-Sleep -Seconds 1

$job2 = Start-Job -FilePath "$currDir/WriteToFileEverySecond.ps1" -ArgumentList "$currDir/Test.txt"

while ($job1.HasMoreData -and $job2.HasMoreData) {
    $job1,$job2 | Receive-Job
}

$job1,$job2 | Stop-Job
$job1,$job2 | Remove-Job

pause
```

---

They are using the following versions:
npm: 6.13.1
gulp cli version: 2.2.0
gulp repo version: 4.0.2